# What is the difference between "vector<pair<int,int>> q;" and "vector<pair<int,int> > q;"

Tags: c++, vector

I get compile error with the former but latter works just fine.

> error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list

Thanks

Comment: The difference is a white-space, obviously. The error message is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: Older versions of C++ required a space between `>`s in nested templates. I think this ugliness has been fixed in more modern versions of the standard, though.

Comment: @UweKeim: Given the nature of the ambiguity and the notorious quality of C++ template compiler diagnostics, I'd actually be surprised if the error were anywhere near "clear".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before C++11, you had to use whitespace to separate the angle brackets in nested templates - otherwise the compiler was interpreting it as right-shift operator ">>". In C++11, you can ommit the whitespace and it will be interpreted as brackets.

However some compilers (eg. MSVC++) ignore the standard and allow you to ommit the whitespace even when not using C++11 standard.

Answer (score 9):

In the (now obsolete) revisions C++98 and C++03, the character sequence ">>" was unconditionally interpreted as the "right shift operator" token, so if you wanted to close multiple template argument lists, you would need to leave some intervening whitespace.

As of C++11, the lexical rules of the language have been modified to interpret ">>" as two consecutive template argument list ends, and the whitespace is no longer necessary. (However, this makes it necessary to parenthesize shift expressions in a template argument list.)

(In the same wash, C++11 also interprets `<::foo`, when used as the first template argument, in the "obvious" way (beginning of argument list, followed by namespace qualifier) rather than consuming `<:` as the alternative token for `[`.)